# How can I check if a date in a cell is this week? Script not sheet function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to check if the dates in column A are this week, then show the row.

my problem is my variable "t" is undefined in the debugger and when run i get the following error...

Exception: Invalid argument: date. Should be of type: Date

```
 function weekNumberTest()
{
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
        var v = s.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var data = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "w");//Exception: Invalid argument: date. Should be of type: Date

for (var i = s.getLastRow(); i > 2; i--) 
{
        var t = v[i ];
        if (t != "") 
        {
            var testDateCell=Utilities.formatDate(t, "GMT", "w");
            if (testDateCell==data ) 
            {
                s.showRows(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `for (var i = s.getLastRow() - 1; i > 2; i--) `

Comment: And, perhaps: `var testDateCell=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(t), "GMT", "w");`

Comment: this got it compiling  so thank you for that but it still doesn’t work. it looks like the value of "testDateCell" isnt the week number

Comment: `v` will be a two-dimensional array with many rows and one column, so you may need to change the line defining `t` to `var t = v[i][0]`. Just `v[i]` by itself will return a one-element array.

Comment: issue due to v being 2 dimensional array as the comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dates in current week

```
function weekNumberTest() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1).getValues().flat();
  const wk = parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "w"));
  vs.forEach((d,i) => {
    let w =parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(d),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"w"));
    if(w == wk || w == wk - 1) {//try this for last two weeks. This may not work at beginning of year...I don't know for sure.
      sh.showRows(i + 2);
    } else (
      sh.hideRows(i + 2)
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper im getting an error with you code... "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null "              LINE 4 of your suggestion

Comment: Did you change the sheet name?

Comment: yes fixed that but its showing the dates 13-19 of February.

Comment: Ultimately I actually need last week and this week

Comment: That is the current week.

Comment: sorry I thinking Monday to Sunday my fault.

Comment: how can I adjust this to include last week please?

Comment: I got it...  "if(w == wk ||w==wk-1)"       thanks to both of you Cooper and @Yuri

Answer (score 0):

```
function weekNumberTest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  var v = s.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var data = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "w");

  for (var i = s.getLastRow(); i > 2; i--) {
    var t = new Date(v[i][0]); // <---------------- the error was here
    if (t != "") {
      var testDateCell = Utilities.formatDate(t, "GMT", "w");
      if (testDateCell == data) {
        s.showRows(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To get the dates from this and last week you can change one line this way:

```
if (testDateCell == data || testDateCell == data-1) {
```

**Explanation**

`var v = s.getRange("A1:A").getValues();` it gets you a 2D array `[[a],[b],[c]]`. To get values from the a 2D array you need to use two indexes: `v[0][0]`, `v[0][1]`, `v[0][2]`.

Alternatively you can use the `flat()` method to convert a 2D array into 1D array this way: `var v = s.getRange("A1:A").getValues().flat();`. In this case you can address the values of the array with one index: `v[0]`, `v[1]`, `v[2]`.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and got this error...TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: There is something wrong with your sheet I suppose. Look here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w3UwL4IRDcXZ5z5EBuZEbRjnHzQ1x5YKFrdHQ1s1sk8/edit?usp=sharing  it works fine

Comment: Cooper's code processes the range "A2:A" (not "A1:A" as is in your question) If it works, I suspect your sheet have a header that causes an error. But from your question it's impossible to know. This why screenshots matter.